# Root site .htaccess interferes with WordPress

Tags: regex, wordpress, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I admit, my .htaccess/regex is the weakest part of my game in development. It's a problem, especially today.

I've got a client's root site in ASP, the access on public_html is applied as follows:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|xmlpdf\.cfm|public|dynamic|googlead5e4138365a1f11.html|sitemap.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
Options -Indexes
```

They want to install WordPress in /public_html/inventory. Obviously, the recursive nature of .htaccess is causing huge conflicts. Problem is, I'm not entirely sure how to resolve a conflict of this nature. Not that anyone here needs the review, but the default WP .htaccess is:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I'm hoping someone can tell me how to relinquish the root folder's icy grip on the WordPress sub-folder.

Thanks bunches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be root .htaccess:

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

# skip WP dir
RewriteRule ^inventory(/|$) - [L,NC]

RewriteRule ^$ index.php [L]

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots\.txt|favicon\.ico|xmlpdf\.cfm|public|dynamic|googlead5e4138365a1f11.html|sitemap.xml)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

This should be WP `/inventory/.htaccess`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /inventory/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Awesome, thank you. This will be helpful in the future. Could you explain how the RewriteRule ^inventory(/|$) - [L,NC] control works? That looks like begin - inventory - slash - end string - last - case insensitive. I have no idea why it's causing the inventory directory to be skipped in the processing. Basically, I don't have a clue, but I'd really like one :)

Comment: Ya sure. `NC` is for ignore case match. Regex is `^inventory(/|$)` which means match URI starting with `inventory` followed by `/` OR end of input. So it will match any of  `/inventory, /inventory/, /inventory/anything, /INVENTORY` etc. `-` is for taking no action if any of those matches are found.

Comment: Ok so you basically wrote a rule with no condition, and that caused no action to be taken?

Comment: No condition is there in the form of regex just action is not there which means skip any rule down below if regex matches.

Comment: You just explained about half of what I never knew about mod_rewrite. Lots of things make much more sense now. Having a bit of a doge moment here.